# Separar info de un String (python)

Tags: python

En base al siguiente String:

```
fecha = '4 de julio de 1995 (edad 23\xa0años), Siracusa, Nueva York, Estados Unidos'
```

Con un Split separo las palabras:

```
split = fecha.split(',')
split[1], split[2], split[3]
     Output: (' Siracusa', ' Nueva York', ' Estados Unidos')
```

Como puedo en este string eliminar lo que esta entre paréntesis y que me quede solo la fecha.

```
split[0]
     Output: '4 de julio de 1995 (edad 23\xa0años)'
```

> Resultado Final: 4 de julio de 1995

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se me ocurre que puede hacer un `split` mas:

```
  final = split[0].split('(')
```

daría como resultado:

> final[0]
>
> '4 de julio de 1995'

Comment: Perfecto, ya tenia la info scrapeada de google y la función de convertir meses a números me faltaba solo eso... tengo que leer mas la documentación -_-, muchas gracias!

Comment: de nada! python es increible..